# Count how many times you exit route the car

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a question, im on a project GPS, 
When a car on route save in our database a value = 1, but when this go off route save in our database a value=0, so how can i determine the number of times out of route from an SQL query?

This is a example of our table:

[image: Example table with datas]

Then if you look the pic, value 1 car is on route and 0 car is off route, i want count the values groups, for example my result will be:

**Off Route = 2 (times)**

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Depending on your database, there may be an easier version with `window functions` such as `lead` and `lag`.  However, this should be generic with `exists`:

```
select count(y1.id) 
from yourtable y1 
where y1.value = 0 and exists (
    select 1 
    from yourtable y2 
    where y2.id = y1.id - 1 and y2.value = 1)
```

Comment: @IsmaelRenteria -- unfortunately 2008 doesn't support `lead` or `lag`, so this is probably your best option...

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cteBase as (
    Select *,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Order by ID) From YourTable
)
Select A.* 
 From  cteBase A
 Join  cteBase B on (A.RowNr=B.RowNr+1 and A.Value=0 and B.Value=1)
```

Returns

```
ID  Value   RowNr
4   0       4
6   0       6
```

I didn't want to assume the ID was incremental so I used Row_Number().  If incremental @sgeddes works just as well

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is just the number of times `Value` is 1 as on Route and 0 as Off Route, try the following query:

```
select 
sum(Value) as [On_route],
sum(abs(Value-1)) as [Off_Route] 
from GPSTable
```

`abs(Value-1)` essentially coverts 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 which is easy enough to check,